# Android Patten Lock API

Tags: java, android, security, api, locking

I'm checking several option of security for my app, I was wondering is there any way I can combine lock screen such as Android's "Pattern Lock" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern lock is not a widget in the SDK that you can drop into a layout file.

However, Android is open source, so the source code to the pattern lock should be available. Since the lock is used in two places -- the lock screen and the Settings app where you set the pattern -- there is a chance that it could be copied into a standalone widget.

Or, you might see if somebody else has created an open source package for it or an equivalent widget.